# I cant create a Jelly Bean emulator

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create an emulator with the AVD tool through Eclipse/Android plugin.  It will not make the 'OK' button clickable for a Level 17 API.  Here is a screenshot.
[image]
If I select a device it will automatically go to the API for that device and I dont have any devices that are 'running' Jelly Bean.  I have downloaded all of the packages for the Jelly Bean SDK, but I still am doing something wrong.  If I select the device first, it still wont let me choose an API Level 17.  Choosing the Galaxy 7 or the Nexus 7 gives me the same result.
[image]

Comment: select which type of device you want. After that you can change the **Target API** to whichever one you want.

Answer (score 1):

First select either Galaxy Nexus or Nexus 7 device from device list. Then you can select API level 17 and it creates AVD accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I had to choose a device, change the api, and then choose a CPU/ABI.  This then allowed me to create the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you select some particular device then it will need to download that device, choose something else.
e.g.
Device:-  `4.0" WVGA(400x800:hdpi).`

if you downloaded all packages then it should create AVD without any trouble

Answer (score 0):

**First Select a device and then you can select the target API as 17...** *For EXAMPLE*-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You does not **select any device.Please select a device by clicking the spinner/listbox** which is mentioned as **"Device"** in your screen

Please refer the image given below
[image]